# Recording and calculating rich elapsed times with Noda Time

Tags: c#, .net, nodatime

I'd like to accurately track key instants for a session object (representing a remote resource), and here is what I would like to do:

1. Record key events, such as the session start time
2. Display rich time information to the user when asked
3. Have the ability to calculate elapsed times between any event, such as the time relative to the session start time

I have some test code where I can successfully gather all of the information that I need, and I'm using `IClock` as a basis to start with instants, from which I can create `ZonedDateTime` and `LocalDateTime` values. I've yet to find any examples other than calculating days and months (using `Period`). I need to record and display times (e.g. the elapsed time since the session started) at least down to the second.

Are they any examples like this out there? I searched around and have not found anything yet.

Using the BCL, this would be a job for `TimeSpan`. But I want the much richer data provided by Noda Time for a number of reasons (and for consistency in other areas where I am using Noda Time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are just looking for the `Duration` structure.  Something like this?

```
IClock clock = SystemClock.Instance;
Instant i1 = clock.Now;

// some time later...
Instant i2 = clock.Now;
Duration d = i2 - i1;
```

You may be able to find more examples by searching Stack Overflow using the [nodatime](/questions/tagged/nodatime) tag.

See also, the [core types quick reference](http://nodatime.org/1.2.x/userguide/core-types.html) in the Noda Time user guide.

If you need something more specific, please edit your question to elaborate.  Thanks.

Comment: Wow, now that is simple... Now that I see how duration works (!), this has illuminated a pivot point around which I can build some sweet helper methods. Thank you, Matt! Bravo!